# Go mysql driver hangs on connect

Tags: mysql, go

I met some weird situation with such simple code:

```
func InitDatabase(dataSourceName string) {

    var err error
    DBCon, err = sql.Open("mysql", dataSourceName)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("Ping...")

    if err = DBCon.Ping(); err != nil { // <- it hangs here
        log.Println(":(")
    }

    log.Println(":)")
}
```

I debugged and found, that it locks goroutine in this line (fd_poll_runtime.go, line #85), looks like it even doesn't connect:

```
res := runtime_pollWait(pd.runtimeCtx, mode)
```

It can wait here for ages, my mac becomes very hot.

I made a small change:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
defer cancel()
if err = DBCon.PingContext(ctx); err != nil {
    log.Println(":(")
}

log.Println(":)")
```

And it still hangs and timeout doesn't work.

Problem is, that it worked yesterday (and, funny, it works on my friend's machine, same params) and now it doesn't even after reboot and after reinstalling mysql (which works perfectly in terminal/goland/mysqlworkbench).

Go version 1.9, mysql driver: "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql", mysql version: 5.7.20 Homebrew, macos version: High Sierra 10.13.1, I host mysql on localhost, port 3306.

**UPDATE**

It finally worked. I copied init code to the clean project and it worked there. I started to comment out code, to find where is the problem. I found that I have this code in the imported package. Even if code from this package executes after database ping, but init code executes before and somehow it blocks `db.Ping()`:

```
func init() {
    for i := 1; i <= maxWorkers; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            for {
                select {
                case j, ok := <-jobs:
                    if ok {
                        j.invoke()
                    } else {
                        // loop
                    }
                default:
                    // loop
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
}
```

I rewrote method name and executed it after database ping and everything worked.

I don't know why it happened, but if you have the answer, feel free to post it here.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with mysql.

Comment: @Flimzy strange thing is that mysql works from CLI or in another way and only this one fails

Comment: Try to use tcpdump to capture what is sent and recived back from the mysql server.

Comment: I've had similar problems w/ psql, usually it had to do with a transaction currently ongoing so the db waits on all other requests.

Comment: @BenjaminKadish problem is, that this is simple init function, and I don't run any queries except Ping(), also I restarted mysql server, restarted laptop and go program :|